# Troubleshooting failed CDRW/DVD drive on old laptop

Tags: dvd

My laptop (HP NX9005, bought in 2003) will no longer read cds or DVDs in Windows XP or Ubuntu.

In Windows, the drive is displayed in *My Computer*, but when I click on the icon it displays an empty disc.

In Ubuntu, the drive is displayed in *Computer*, but when I click on the icon it gives me the error

> **Unable to mount location**
>
> No media in the drive

While the computer is on, in both operating systems, the status light on the drive continually blinks.

I have also tried setting the bios to boot from the CDRW/DVD drive by default, but goes straight to GRUB on the hard disk.

I have checked that the CDs and DVDs that I am testing the drive with work on another computer.

Are there any suggestions for trouble shooting the problem, before I accept that the drive is dead?

Answer (score 3):

If your computer can't read disks at the bios level, there isn't much else to check (though you could try a cleaning disk). Just get a new DVD drive, it's only like $30/$40 for laptop drives on newegg ([linky](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010100005%201036508690&name=Slim%20Combo%20Drive)) (as of Aug 5 2009).

Comment: New drives might be cheap, but I think replacing the drive might be tricky. I've changed the hard disk and added RAM before, but the CDRW/DVDdrive seems to be built into the case. My quick google search didn't bring up any instructions for replacing the optical drive.

Comment: Some drive replacements are easier than installing USB memory, and some are impossible (I'm looking at you, Sony). Yours seems to be harder than most, but I found instructions here: http://www.bixnet.com/cohpnoopdrin.html You have to remove the keyboard, but you don't have to touch anything spooky.